# java: how to manipulate data array in main class?

Tags: java

This is called `GoHomeAction.java`

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_H;

public class GoHomeAction extends BrowserAction {

    public GoHomeAction(BrowsersTabbedPane controller) {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //need to add to data[] which is located in MainClass.java

    }
}
```

in this action, I need to add to the `data[]` which is located in one of the functions inside `MainClass.java`

how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is any data you need at the start of your application throughout your applications life cycle, you will need to store it in memory or via some other technology (database) to make use of downstream.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to pass in the information into the class, or to make the information available statically from the MainClass:

```
//as an example of static:
public static final MyObject[] data[] = new MyObject[100];
```

However, globals are, in general, an antipattern.  Especially if they are being modified.  If you need to touch it, maybe you need a carrier object to move it around better.  Where does this data belong?  Does it really belong in the MainClass, or should someone else be the owner of the data?  These are good questions to ask when designing the class structure and interaction behavior.

Good Luck!